# Interacting with HtmlUnit List item

Tags: java, android, html, htmlunit

I have a web form that I am trying to fill in via code using HtmlUnit.

I am stuck in the interacting stage with a List Item. I need to display the data to the user and then select the values in the web page form, but the only methods available according to the API are:

```
String  getTypeAttribute() - Returns the value of the attribute "type".  
String  getValueAttribute() - Returns the value of the attribute "value".
```

How do I go about selecting the list, displaying it to the user, and then taking their input and setting it on the form?

Answer (score 0):

ok there was an htmlselect which i overlooked about ten times :D sorry!